# Camel Exchange property not evaluating with simple in xml

Tags: properties, apache-camel

I'm trying to set a property isEven on the Exchange.property and then use **choice**  **when**  to evaluate it in the route.
  The property is being set but I am always getting the **otherwise** result (NACK) no matter what isEven is set to.

Here is where I set it:

```
// Below is used for development
// If the property.isEven == true then an ACK will be returned from the Mock HRM
// If false then NACK

    int lastDigit = Integer.parseInt(exchange.getExchangeId().substring(exchange.getExchangeId().length() - 1));

    // check if lastDigit is odd or even
    if ((lastDigit & 1) == 0)
    {
        exchange.setProperty("isEven", Boolean.TRUE);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n********** Exchange Id lastDigit " + lastDigit + " isEven: " + exchange.getProperty("isEven") + " ***********");

    }
    else
    {
        exchange.setProperty("isEven", Boolean.FALSE);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n********** Exchange Id lastDigit " + lastDigit + " isEven: " + exchange.getProperty("isEven") + " ***********");

    }
```

The println's show that I am setting isEven the way I expect.
Here is the route:

```
<!-- Used to ramdomly send Ack or Nack -->
<log message="isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}" />
    <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
            <simple>"${property[isEven]}"</simple>
                <transform>
            <constant>ACK</constant>
            </transform>    
        </camel:when>
        <camel:otherwise>
            <transform>
            <constant>NACK</constant>
        </transform>    
        </camel:otherwise>
    </camel:choice>
```

The log message never evaluates the expression ${property[isEven]}
Here is the output
    log[isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}]

if I change the simple expression to explicitly check for true I alway get ACK no matter what the property is set to.

```
<simple>"${property[isEven]} == true"</simple>
```

I have searched the web but couldn't find a lot of examples using simple and Exchange property.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Andrew

After Peter showed he could do it easily I tried 2 of his examples that I hadn't tried already.  Here is one.  It didn't work for me.  It generated Hello :: NACK whether isEven is true or false:

```
<camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <simple>${property[isEven]} == "true"</simple>
                <log message="HELLO :: ACK" />
                <!-- <transform>
                    <constant>ACK</constant>
                </transform> -->    
            </camel:when>
            <camel:otherwise>
                <log message="HELLO :: NACK" />
                <!-- <transform>
                    <constant>NACK</constant>
                </transform> -->    
            </camel:otherwise>
        </camel:choice>
```

Here is something interesting.  It looks below like the log is saying its empty  On the last like

```
********** Exchange Id lastDigit 2 isEven: true ***********

14/02/20 14:09:13 INFO interceptor.Tracer: >>> (toHRMRoute) bean://hl7handler?method=handleORM --> log[isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}] <<< Pattern:InOut, Properties {CamelToEndpoint=bean://hl7handler?method=handleORM, CamelMessageHistory [DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=toHRMRoute, node=to3], DefaultMessage History[routeId=toHRMRoute, node=log1]], CamelCreatedTimestamp=Thu Feb 20 14:09:13 CST 2014}

14/02/20 14:09:13 INFO toHRMRoute:  ** isEven property is :: **
```

I think Peter is correct in that it has to be the way I have my routes set up.

```
<endpoint id="hrmMockHL7Listener"
        uri="netty:tcp://localhost:9200?sync=true" />
<!-- Sending data using postman to a rest server-->
<route id="pushRESTRoute">
<from uri="cxfrs://bean://pushRESTServer" />

    <!-- this process is where we set isEven on the Exchange-->
<process ref="transformer"/>
    <!-- Send it to a tcp listener at port 9200-->
<to ref="hrmMockHL7Listener" /> 
</route>
<!-- Changed routes does the Exchange keep properties? -->
<route id="toMRoute">
<from uri="hrmMockHL7Listener" />
<to uri="bean:hl7handler?method=handleORM" />
<!-- Used to ramdomly send Ack or Nack -->
<log message="isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}">
    // see the beginning of the question for choice code.
```

Looking at the output it seems the isEven property is being dropped between routes:

```
14/02/21 09:37:26 INFO interceptor.Tracer: >>> (pushRESTRoute) ref:transformer --> tcp://localhost:9200 <<< Pattern:InOut, Properties {CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=pushRESTRoute, node=process1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=pushRESTRoute, node=to1]], CamelCreatedTimestamp=Fri Feb 21 09:37:26 CST 2014, isEven=true}
```

See isEven at the end?  The next tracer that comes doesn't have it

```
/02/21 09:37:26 INFO interceptor.Tracer: >>> (toMRoute) from(tcp://localhost:9200) --> bean://hl7handler?method=handleORM <<< Pattern:InOut, Properties:{CamellMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=toMRoute, node=to3]], CamelCreatedTimestamp=Fri Feb 21 09:37:26 CST 2014}
```

From the Exchange javadoc

```
An Exchange is the message container holding the information during the entire routing of a Message received by a Consumer.
```

Does *entire* include across differents routes?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Answer (score 3):

For testing I changed the route a little bit:

```
<route id="startRoute">
    <from uri="direct:start" />
    <multicast stopOnException="true">
        <to uri="direct:trigger" />
        <to uri="direct:trigger" />
        <to uri="direct:trigger" />
    </multicast>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:trigger" />
    <process ref="myProcessor" />
    <log message="isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}" />
    <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
            <simple>"${property.isEven}"</simple> 
            <log message="HELLO :: ACK" />
        </camel:when>
        <camel:otherwise>
            <log message="HELLO :: NACK" />
        </camel:otherwise>
    </camel:choice>
</route>

<!-- scope singleton is default -->
<bean id="myProcessor" class="ch.keller.test.testcamelspring.util.Trigger"  scope="singleton" />
```

The processor is defined as follows:

```
public class Trigger implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // your code comes here
    }
}
```

For me, following expressions worked as expected:

```
<simple>"${property[isEven]}"</simple>
```

or

```
<simple>${property[isEven]}</simple>
```

or

```
<simple>${property[isEven]} == "true"</simple>
```

or

```
<simple>"${property.isEven}"</simple>
```

or

```
<simple>${property.isEven} == "true"</simple>
```

or

```
<simple>${property.isEven}</simple>
```

I prefer the last version.

**EDIT:**

In order to debug if the property is correctly set, enable `showProperties` in your Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="traceFormatter" class="org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultTraceFormatter">
    <property name="showBreadCrumb" value="false" />
    <property name="showProperties" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Then you should see following output in your log (shorten for better readability):

```
[main] Tracer INFO  >>> (route1) log[isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}] --> choice <<< Pattern:InOnly, Properties:{CamelToEndpoint=direct://trigger, ..., isEven=true, ...
```

The important part is `isEven=true`.

**EDIT:**

The property is kept when forwarding to another route which can be proven as follows:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:trigger" />
    <process ref="myProcessor" />
    <log message="isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}" />
    <to uri="direct:acktarget" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:acktarget" />
    <log message="acktarget: isEven property is :: ${property[isEven]}" />
</route>
```

Output:

```
exchange.getExchangeId() = ID-pis-iMac-local-54434-1393006139076-0-3
********** Exchange Id lastDigit 3 isEven: false ***********
[                          main] route1                         INFO  isEven property is :: false
[                          main] route2                         INFO  acktarget: isEven property is :: false
exchange.getExchangeId() = ID-pis-iMac-local-54434-1393006139076-0-4
********** Exchange Id lastDigit 4 isEven: true ***********
[                          main] route1                         INFO  isEven property is :: true
[                          main] route2                         INFO  acktarget: isEven property is :: true
exchange.getExchangeId() = ID-pis-iMac-local-54434-1393006139076-0-5
********** Exchange Id lastDigit 5 isEven: false ***********
[                          main] route1                         INFO  isEven property is :: false
[                          main] route2                         INFO  acktarget: isEven property     is :: false
```

Even if I invoke a bean before forwarding the message to the other route, the property is kept. So, I guess your problems is in `<to uri="bean:hl7handler?method=handleORM" />`. Try to log the property before invoking this bean and see if the property is still set. If not, have a look at the bean.

Comment: Wow.  Now your just making me look bad. ;-)  I'll put in those logs and try a few of your successful examples.

Comment: Peter are you setting it with Boolean.TRUE & Boolean.False?  If your simple expressions don't work for me maybe it how I'm setting them?

Comment: I actually used your processor. But perhaps it has to do a) with how you invoke your route (see my enhanced example above), b) with if your `myProcessor` has `singelton` (default) or `prototype` scope..

Comment: +1 for the multicast example.  I double checked I did not specify singelton or prototype so I'm using singleton by default.  Did you see I added to the question the detail that the log message is showing isEven as empty.  The log message starts with INFO.

Comment: I added how to debug if the property is correctly set in my answer above.

Comment: I added my routes and the output lookes like isEven is being dropped between routes.

Comment: The property is not dropped between routes see my additional example in my answer. May `hl7handler` change the exchange object?

Comment: I never could get this to work.  I gave Peter a +1 because thats all I could give with out selecting a answer that works for me.  The exchange property that I set was definitely being dropped between routes.  Thanks again for the help but I'm no longer on that contract so I can't continue fixing it.

Comment: @KingAndrew Did you check if `hl7handler` did not erase the properties, e.g. by explicitly setting the `out` message?

Comment: All hl7handler was doing was checking for isEven.

Answer (score 2):

For newer version of apache camel use `exchangeProperty` instead of `property`

> ${exchangeProperty.isEven}

The simple language property function was deprecated in Camel 2.x and has been removed. Use exchangeProperty as function name.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use quotes. Try just

```
<simple>${property.isEven} == true</simple>
```

Comment: That is how I had it to begin with.  I changed it back.  Made sure I saved and re-compiled. :)  And tried it again.  No luck. I get NACK (otherwise) every time.  For the record the isEven does change every time.  The lastDigit starts as 2 and then 7 then repeats.